# How to get a list of selected items from a listview with checkboxes? (Without code behind)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, entity-framework-core

Sorry if the question is unclear or the answer obvious, I have to work on this project for school without having had a deep dive in c# and WPF.

I built a list view with checkboxes following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-listviewitems-with-a-checkbox?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

I would like to simply get the list of all items (category) with a thicked checkbox when I click the button "Filter categories".

I found kind of similar questions with answers involving using code behind which I can't do.

[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding CourseCategories}" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Category"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Display" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
        <Button  Content="Filter Categories" Command="{Binding FilterCategory}" CommandParameter="???" />
```

Should I pass this to the ViewModel with the button CommandParameter? If yes, how?
If no, how can I get the list of selected items in my ViewModel?

The essential of the ViewModel:

```
namespace Project.ViewModel {
    public class QuestionsViewModel : ViewModelCommon {

        private Course course;
        public Course Course { get => course; set => SetProperty(ref course, value, OnRefreshData); }

        private ObservableCollection<Category> courseCategories;
        public ObservableCollection<Category> CourseCategories {
            get => courseCategories;
            set => SetProperty(ref courseCategories, value);
        }

        public ICommand FilterCategory { get; set; }

        public QuestionsViewModel() : base() {

            FilterCategory = new RelayCommand<List<Category>>(categories => {
                foreach (var c in categories) {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.Title);
                }
            });
        }
   
    }
}
```

Should I add a bool property display in the "category" model and bind it to the checkbox?
If yes, I still don't know how to get a list of all thicked items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I add a bool property display in the "category" model and bind it to the checkbox?

Yes.

> If yes, I still don't know how to get a list of all thicked items.

Just filter them out from the `courseCategories` collection, for example using LINQ:

```
var checkedItems = courseCategories.Where(x => x.YourBoolProperty).ToArray():
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's working. I find it weird to have to add a property in the model just for the use of filtering.

Comment: It's not a model. It's a *view*model. Or at least it should be.

Comment: It's working but I must be doing something poorly as I had to add "bool display" in "category" model. I don't see how I can use a bool property display only in the viewmodel without being an attribute of "category".

Comment: I don't follow. You seem to have solved the issue using my suggestion?

Comment: yes, It's working, thanks to you! never mind for the rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to achieve the same thing.

I have added a bool property to the model ("Display").

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding CourseCategories}" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Category" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Display" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Display}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
        <Button  Content="Filter Categories" {Binding FilterCategory}"  Style="{StaticResource DarkBlueButton}"  />
```

Bound the checkbox with display in the ViewModel

```
public bool? Display {
            get { return Display; }
            set { Display = value; }
               
        }
```

```
public ICommand FilterCategory { get; set; }

        public QuestionsViewModel() : base() {
            
            FilterCategory = new RelayCommand(() => {
                var checkedItems = courseCategories.Where(x => x.Display).ToArray();
                foreach (var c in checkedItems) {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.Title);
                }
            });
        }
```